# JSOUP extract text including the <br>, &nbsp; and <strong>

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to extract a text from a div tag from an HTML URL source using JSOUP which is:

```xhtml
<div class="some_text">
    <strong>Lorem ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, <br />&nbsp;<br />sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br /><br />Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
```

Using this code:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();           
Elements description = document.select("div[class=some_text]");
String getText = description.text();
```

The output is:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

As you can see the spaces and strong tag are not reflecting on the output of the text which are the `<br />, &nbsp; and <strong>`. What I wanted is that the spaces and bold emphasis to the text output to be included. How to achieve this?

My desired output would be:

> **Lorem ipsum** dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
>
> sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
>
> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
>   nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Comment: Try using `description.html()` instead of `text()`

Comment: Hello thank you for answering. What I meant is that the tags such as <br> and <strong> should reflect on the output. For example the one with the <strong>Lorem ipsum</strong> should be bold. Sames as to <br> which will print the actual space. It seems that JSOUP ignores all the HTML tags.

Comment: But that's the display, not the string.  What are you doing with this extracted description?

Comment: Oh sorry for my english. The display is what I meant. :)
I wanted the extracted description as accurate as the markup (tags)?

Comment: And what do you want to do with that description?  The `strong`, etc. markup only makes sense on display, while `br` does mean something in storage.